# Creating recursive tree of processes using fork()

Tags: c, linux, unix, recursion, fork

I'm trying to generate a tree of processes. An example can be seen in the picture which would be the expected result running the program with the parameter 5.

When the program finishes it's only the processes at the last level (the leafs) that are supposed to print their pid.

When I run the program with the level parameter 1 it outputs 1 process. If levels = 2 output = 3 processes. Level = 3, output = 2 processes. Level = 4, output = 6 processes. Level = 5, output = 4 processes.

As you can see all the odd levels give the right amount of processes but the even ones don't. The expected result is 1 process for level 2 and 2 processes for level 4.

[image]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void startProcess(int level, int max);
void fork_r(int level, int max);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int n;

    if(argc != 2){
        printf("Wrong number of arguments");
        exit(-1);
    }

    n = atoi(argv[1]);
        if(n <= 0){
        printf("Insert positive integer as argument");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

   fork_r(1, n); //start from level one and go until n

   return 0;
}

void fork_r(int level, int max){
    if(level > max){
         printf("Process: %d \n", getpid()); //if recursion done print pid of leafs
         return;
    }
    if(level % 2 != 0){ 
        startProcess(level, max);
        exit(0); 
    } else {
        startProcess(level, max);
        startProcess(level, max);
        exit(0);
    }
}

void startProcess(int level, int max){
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if(pid == 0){
        fork_r(level + 1, max);
   } else 
        return;
}
```

Comment: I suggest you start by doing some [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging), closely followed by adding a *lot* more output so it's easy to follow the flow of your program.

Answer (score 2):

The sensible part using `fork()` is to never forget that when a new process is created, you get two processes living: one common mistake is to handle the child case (`if fork() == 0 { child code }`) and overlook the fact that the child will also execute the code *after* the child code, if not properly separated. Which might involuntarily lead to a [fork bomb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_bomb).

Suggested code for `fork_r()` (recursive indeed)

```
void fork_r(int me, int max) {
    if (me == max) {
        printf("Level %d, pid %ld\n", me, (long)getpid());
    }
    else {
        if (fork() == 0) {
            fork_r(me+1, max);
        }
        else if (!(me & 1)) {   // Note the 'else'
            fork_r(me+1, max);
        }
    }
}
```

The code above makes a `fork()` and, *in the parent*, tests for an even level in which case another `fork()` is performed.